# Why doesn't Magick-config ship with the version of ImageMagick installed by yum on RHEL6?

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

I'm trying to install some Ruby gems, and one called Rmagick, which interfaces with ImageMagick, is failing.

It's trying to find "Magick-config", but there does not appear to be any such animal in:

ImageMagick-6.5.4.7-5.el6.x86_64

Here's the specific failure:

Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!
/home/akwf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:552:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

```
    /home/akwf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no

and then it bails.

***UPDATE***

I needed to get the rpm, since the ImageMagick-devel package I needed was not available in any RHEL6 yum repo that I knew how to find. Here's what I dug up:

```
yum install gcc-c++
yum install ImageMagick
yum install bzip2-devel
yum install freetype-devel
yum install jasper
yum install libX11-devel
yum install libXext-devel
yum install libXt-devel
yum install libjpeg-devel
yum install libtiff-devel

# Not available in RHEL6 yum repo
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.2/updates/x86_64/Packages/ghostscript-devel-8.70-    11.el6_2.6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -iv ghostscript-devel-8.70-11.el6_2.6.x86_64.rpm

# Not available in RHEL6 yum repo
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/jasper-devel-1.900.1-15.el6_1.1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -iv jasper-devel-1.900.1-15.el6_1.1.x86_64.rpm

# Not available in RHEL6 yum repo
wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/6.2/os/x86_64/Packages/lcms-devel-1.19-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -iv lcms-devel-1.19-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

# Not available in RHEL6 yum repo
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/ImageMagick-devel-6.5.4.7-5.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -iv ImageMagick-devel-6.5.4.7-5.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Everything listed above the last rpm command are dependencies for install ImageMagick-devel. There may be a few more that I already had installed. If so, just Google the specific version and hunt it down on rpmfind or pkgs.org. If you find something, add it in a comment and I'll update this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to install an ImageMagick-devel package to get the development tools and headers?

**EDIT** Sorry - not a very useful answer - I was on my way out of the office.

Many software packages for Linux systems seem to be split into two parts - the main binaries, libs, docs, etc in one, and the development resources (header files, additional utilities and development documentation) in the other. In this case, the Magick-config utility is part of the ImageMagick-devel package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. I was kind of stranded after wondering why the -devel package wasn't available in a yum repo for EL6. I had to get the rpm. Normally not a big deal until I ended up in dependency hell. I was able to work through it. Noted above.